# Date formatting according to the culture

Tags: window, date-format

Have made a `custom datepicker` which is in `seperate dll` , I want it to return date in `dd/mm/yyyy format` but it is taking default US culture and `returning mm/dd/yyyy format` how should I `config culture` for the custom datepicker so that dont have to individually convert the format in every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for setting culture, too.

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // Creating a Global culture specific to our application.
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    // Creating the DateTime Information specific to our application.
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeInfo = 
    new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
    // Defining various date and time formats.
    dateTimeInfo.DateSeparator = "/";
    dateTimeInfo.LongDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    dateTimeInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
    dateTimeInfo.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt";
    dateTimeInfo.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";
    // Setting application wide date time format.
    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat = dateTimeInfo;
    // Assigning our custom Culture to the application.
    Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    ..................
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the UI culture and culture for all pages, add a globalization section to the Web.config file, and then set the uiculture and culture attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

To set the UI culture and culture for an individual page, set the Culture and UICulture attributes of the @ Page directive, as shown in the following example:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

for more information click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok then also you can use and set culture from app.config file using first example. for another stuff, refer my second answer.